# Make Flash Parent Fade Out & adding sound BrickBreaker Game

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Hi i am trying to get this brick to fade out when the ball hits it in my brickbreaker game in flash AS3. Here is the code. At the moment there is just a removechild function which makes it just dissapear i want to know how to make it fade out instead. Also i have a breaking sound i would like to add when the ball hits the brick and wonder how i would add this aswell?

EDIT: I have managed to add sound by using Var & Play after the remove child line

```
package {
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;

public class Brick extends MovieClip {
    private var _root:MovieClip;
    public function Brick(){
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED, beginClass);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameEvents);
    }
    private function beginClass(event:Event):void{
        _root = MovieClip(root);
    }
    private function enterFrameEvents(event:Event):void{
        if(this.hitTestObject(_root.Ball)){
            _root.ballYSpeed *= -1;
            this.parent.removeChild(this);
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameEvents);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for any tweener pack for just one tween.

You can use the Tween class provided in AS3 itself. Try this :

```
new Tween(mc,"alpha", 
          Strong.easeIn,
          mc.alpha,
          0,
          2,
          true).addEventListener(
          TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, 
          function() { removeChild(mc); }, 
          false, 0, true);
```

Note:

- mc is the movieclip (or the brick).
- The code removes the movieclip from stage after the tween completes.
- You may play the sound as soon as the ball touches the brick & put
  this code after that.
- The last three parameters (false, 0, true) set the motion finish listener to be garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

How I would do it would be to first create a variable hit:Boolean and set it to true when it gets hit and change your code inside enterFrameEvents function to something like this

```
if(!hit && this.hitTestObject(_root.Ball)){
        hit = true;
        _root.ballYSpeed *= -1;
        //this.parent.removeChild(this);
        //removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameEvents);
    }
if(hit){
        this.alpha -= 0.1; //change value to preference
        if(this.alpha <= 0){
             this.parent.removeChild(this);
             removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameEvents);
        }
    }
```

Comment: ive fiddled around with it a bit but cant get it to work it says access of undefined property "hit"

Comment: I've just downloaded a tweener pack which seemed to do the trick :)